# Separating pieces of a term

Tags: list-manipulation

In a list I have, there are two pieces per term like so: "name (country)". Is there a way to separate the name and country into separate "columns" so it appears as "name, country"?

Comment: The first 3 terms of my list look like this: "{Ella Brown (Great Britain)}, {Tori O'Brien (Germany)}, {Catherine Gregory (USA)}" and I want to produce: "{Ella Brown, Great Britain}, {Tori O'Brien,Germany}, {Catherine Gregory, USA}"

Comment: Please post your sample input and output in Mathematica code. It's ambiguous as it is. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful